# Прокрутка страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Есть сайт, его высота скажем 300vh (3 экрана пользователя)

Пользователь начинает скроллить, как сделать что бы в первом случае (при взгляде на "первый экран"), прокрутка происходила до второго экрана? При этом, в остальных случаях прокрутка оставалась нормальной.

[image: кортинка]

Comment: https://codepen.io/umarhamza/pen/cgqex

Comment: @entithat
Спасибо!

Comment: Ещё похоже: https://jsfiddle.net/jtpbq9zf/, **Но** лично у меня `on('mousewheel'...` не работает в Хроме.